# gsub function using if statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a gsub function that replaces text within a column which works well. However, I now face an issue where I wish to replace certain text within the column but only for specific conditions, otherwise I wish to leave it as is.

The existing code looks like this:

```
myfulldata$Waypoint <- gsub("Old", "New", myfulldata$Waypoint, fixed = TRUE)
```

I now wish to have an if statement where I only replace the old text with the new text if the Sales.Year value = 2018 and Sales.Month=1 or 2. Can an if statement be nested within the formula?

I have looked at the exception case within the gsub formula but this seemed to only be for specific text within the column being replaced.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: myfulldata$Waypoint <- gsub("Old","New",myfulldata$Waypoint, fixed=TRUE) This is my existing code for replacing Old with new, but I've no idea how to include an if statement within this, or if it's possible.

Comment: That is the same code in your post.  I meant an example with `myfulldata$Waypoint` 2-3 elements

Comment: Use a condition `i1 <- with(myfulldata, Sales.Year == 2018 & Sales.Month %in% 1:2); myfulldata$Waypoint[i1] <- gsub("Old","New",myfulldata$Waypoint[i1], fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: if(myfulldata$Waypoint=="Old")&(myfulldata$Sales.Year=="2018")&(myfulldata$Sales.Year=="1")
{
  gsub("Old","New",myfulldata$Waypoint, fixed=TRUE)
}
else
{  No action}
}

Comment: ok thanks I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `ifelse` statement to selectively replace as follows:

```
myfulldata$New_Col <- ifelse(myfulldata$Sales.Year == 2018 & (myfulldata$Sales.Month == 1 | myfulldata$Sales.Month == 2), 
                             gsub("Old","New",myfulldata$Waypoint, fixed=TRUE),
                             myfulldata$Waypoint)
```

I have created a new column where it will check for the condition and then replace it with the `gsub` output only if the condition matches. Else it will keep it the same

Comment: Thanks very much. This was exactly what I needed, works.